# Dynamic name of a variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, ng-bind

I'm doing an AngularJS application and I end up with this problem:

I have some text that it has to be dynamic... the text will be reacheable in the following variable:

"scope.text.text_*id*"

The problem is to set this *id* variable with angular's {{}}

I can't use as an array instead of an object because i have tons of empty ids so it would be most of it useless

Any ideas?

Thank in advice to anyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this is just plain javascript. You can set a property on an object using the [] operator on the object.

The code for angular would be something like this:

In the controller:

```
$scope.id = "myprop";
$scope.text = {};
$scope.text['text_' + $scope.id] = "myValue";
```

And in the directive:

```
{{text["text_" + id]}}
```

I made this plunker showing the behaviour.
http://plnkr.co/edit/72mHY2AxQgwqTuXX9Myd

Answer (score 3):

Providing that you have scope property `id` you can use bracket notation like this to access dynamic text from object `scope.text`:

```
{{ text['text_' + id] }}
```